# SQL Server Compact throwing exception over unknown data type?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server-ce

In SQL Server Compact edition how do you define an integer when creating a database programatically? I've tried `int`, `Int32`, `Bigint`, none of them work, they all throw an exception saying the data type is not valid?

```
string createTable6 = "CREATE TABLE Gates (Gate1In Bigint(5), Gate1Out Bigint(5), Gate2In Bigint(5), Gate2Out Bigint(5), Gate3In Bigint(5), Gate3Out Bigint(5), Gate4In Bigint(5), Gate4Out Bigint(5), Gate5In Bigint(5), Gate5Out Bigint(5))";

SqlCeConnection connexion6 = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
SqlCeCommand table6 = new SqlCeCommand(createTable6, connexion6);

try
{
    connexion6.Open();
    table6.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}

connexion6.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `bigint` without parenthesis

```
string createTable6 = "CREATE TABLE Gates (Gate1In bigint, Gate1Out bigint, " + 
       "Gate2In bigint, Gate2Out bigint, Gate3In bigint, Gate3Out bigint, " + 
       "Gate4In bigint, Gate4Out bigint, Gate5In bigint, Gate5Out bigint)";
```

However it should work also with `int`. And if you don't really need all that integer space (8 bytes) you could use ints

Answer (score 1):

It is the fact you have parentheses after the data type declaration:

Try this:

```
string createTable6 = "CREATE TABLE Gates (Gate1In Bigint, Gate1Out Bigint, Gate2In Bigint, " + 
       "Gate2Out Bigint, Gate3In Bigint, Gate3Out Bigint, Gate4In Bigint, Gate4Out Bigint, " +
       "Gate5In Bigint, Gate5Out Bigint)";
```